# About floor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am stuck with these two floor function problems.

Please help me

> 1.
>   Let r be a real number, and n be a positive integer. 
> Prove
>   $[r]+[r+\frac1n]+...+[r+\frac{n-1}n]=[nr]$
>
> 2.
>   Let S be set of integers given by $[\alpha x]$ and $[\beta x]$ for x=1,2,3,... 
> Prove that S consists of every integer, each appearing exactly once, iff $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are positive irrational numbers such that $\frac1\alpha+\frac1\beta=1$

Thank you

Comment: 2 is betty's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Part 1 hint:

Consider the value of $r-[r]$.

Comment: I tried to a state and not move on. $[\{r\}+\frac1n]+[\{r\}+\frac2n]+...+[\{r\}+\frac{n-1}n]=[n\{r\}]$ where {r}=r-[r]. How can I move to the next step?

Comment: @SimplyComplex, $\dfrac{k}{n} \le \{r\} < \dfrac{k+1}{n}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 \le k \le n-1$.